# Creating bootstrap paging and searching using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I make the paging by bootstrapping was normal, and I try to add the paging searching but can not work when the next paging click.

```
    function cari() {
        $start = $this->input->post ('mulai_tgl');
        $end = $this->input->post ('sampai_tgl');
        $get = array('start' => $start,'end'   => $end );

        $pelanggan = $this->pelanggan_m->get_data($get);

        if ($start == "" || $end == "") {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 
                    '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                    Tanggal Harus di isi &nbsp;&nbsp;</div>');
            redirect('admin/pelanggan');        
        } else {
        $num_rows = $this->db->get('tb_pelanggan');
        $config['base_url'] = site_url('admin/pelanggan/cari/'.$get.'');
        $config['total_rows'] = $num_rows->num_rows();
        $config['per_page'] = 3;    
        $config['uri_segment'] = 4; 


        $this->pagination->initialize($config);         
        $data['page'] = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;  

            $data=array('title'     =>'KOPKAR - Pelanggan',
                        'halaman'   =>$this->pagination->create_links(),
                        'pelanggan' => $this->pelanggan_m->get_data($config['per_page'], $data['page'], $get),
                        'isi'       =>'admin/pelanggan'
            );          
            $this->load->view('dashboard/wrapper',$data);   
        }
}
```

This My module

```
function get_data($num, $offset, $get) 
{
    $this->db->where("tgl_pembelian BETWEEN " . "'" . $get['start'] . "'" . " AND " . "'" . $get['end'] . "'");
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('tb_pelanggan');
    $this->db->join('tb_anggota', 'tb_anggota.id_koperasi = tb_pelanggan.id_koperasi');
    $this->db->order_by("tgl_pembelian","DESC");
    $query = $this->db->get ('',$num, $offset);
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
    {
        return $query->result();
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }    
}
```

Comment: what you want not clear about question.

Comment: thank @SantoshRamKunjir Which, I Face the above problems , when I click search data appearing with pagination , but when I click next page(click paging 2) pagination back to the index not to further data. Please help

Comment: search with pagination need to store or send parameter in url to get search result after click on pagination links like page2 page3...

Comment: Can you give an example like what  @SantoshRamKunjir ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are interested in bootstrap, you could use a plugin

https://datatables.net/

because, you can simply get all the data at once, so no multiple requests and responses going to and from the server, the plugin itself when set will do the pagination, sorting, and searching for you with ease.